# Prove that a uniquely decodable binary scheme hast the average code word length $l = H(S)$ iff all $p_i$ are powers of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I would like to prove the above.
In this notation $\displaystyle H(S) = \sum_{i = 1}^m p_i \log_2(p_i)$ is the entropy.
My idea is to write $l$ as $\displaystyle l = \sum_{i = 1}^m p_i l_i + \log_2(G) \cdot \sum_{i = 1}^m p_i $, where $\displaystyle G = \sum_{i = 1}^m 2^{- l_i}$.
And use that $\log_2(G) = 0$.
Is that a good approach? And if so has someone an idea how i would prove $G = 1$?

Comment: You're In the right track. First, you missed a minus sign for the entropy. Second, about $G=1$:  you can start assuming that's true, write $G= \sum g_i = \sum 2^{-l_i}$ and see if you can prove $l \ge H$ with equality iff $p_i = 2^{-k}$. If you succeed, then revisit the assumption: you actually know $G\le 1$. Then normalize it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think I got the first part. What exactly do you mean by normalizing G?

Comment: Just $ g_i'= 2^{-li}/G$ (which indeeds sum up to one) and work with that.